# How do I submit a Codename One application to the itunes store

Tags: java, app-store-connect, codenameone, itunes-store, application-loader

I've finished the development of my [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) application and tested the debug version. I created an Appstore version and I'm ready to submit it to the itunes store but I'm unsure how to do that.

When I go to Apple's member area site I don't see any area to submit the app or upload it.

I've seen mention that this can be done directly thru `xcode` but since I use Codename One I don't have a Mac or `xcode`.

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic, can someone actually post a reasonable explanation on why they think this is the case? The question above was posted based on a question we got on our support channel.

Comment: I don't understand why it is closed either, so I'll just vote to re-open...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time you need a Mac for the store upload process (this is something we might improve in the future).

You can use a Mac In Cloud machine for that specific task since its a pretty short task.

You need to signup to [itunes connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) (on a PC or Mac).

Define all the settings for your app, images, copy etc. and bring it to the "ready to upload binary" stage.

Then on a Mac with xcode installed (xcode is in the Mac appstore):

- Press the magnifying glass on the top right corner (spotlight)
- Type `Application Loader` (it will suggest completion) and double click that app.
- Login thru the app and follow the steps to upload

Comment: I just received an old Mac (2010) I spent $200 on just to be able to do this and what do I find... I need a 2012+ Mac to even be able to install xCode! Grrrrrr Shai pls make that online Mac available soon... :'(... gotta love Apple

Comment: You just need.Application Loader not the full xcode. Make sure you have the latest version you can install of Mac OS and download versions of Application Loader from Apples developer website. They have a download archive that you can page thru. Newer versions might not work, but one of the older ones might and if so it might allow you to update.

Comment: I have returned the mac... I could order another one and try this but since it's not guaranteed to work I think I will borrow a friend's one for now...

Comment: You can use macincloud which has a free quota you can use just for that

Comment: Thanks I will do that